# How can I refactor this Rails 3 code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anybody figure a way to refactor this further?

```
@hourly_pay = {}
HourlyPay.all.each { |hp| @hourly_pay[t("hourly_pay.#{hp.amount}")] = hp.amount }
```

Thanks!

---

Edit: based on the answers I've received, here's how I refactored

```
HourlyPay.all.map(&:amount).index_by { |hp| t("hourly_pay.#{hp.amount}") }
```

Placing this into my model directly, this becomes

```
  def self.get_options
   all.map(&:amount).index_by { |hp| I18n.t("hourly_pay.#{hp.amount}") }
  end
```

However, I'm not sure if this is more calculation intensive, since I'm calling `map` on the values returned from the database, and then calling `index_by` on that.
Since my HourlyPay model only includes an `id` and an `amount`, I'm not worried about selecting everything. However, if I had a lot more fields, I would do the following instead:

```
def self.get_options
 select(:amount).map(&:amount).index_by { |hp| I18n.t("hourly_pay.#{hp.amount}") }
end
```

So only the amount field is selected

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Give some example of `t("hourly_pay.25")` ?

Comment: it's a localization method provided by rails (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). Example: `t("hourly_pay.neg")` would return "Negotiable" (assuming I defined it in a localization file)

Comment: Yes, I know about `t`, but what I mean is `hourly_pay.23.99` for example, what would that mean?!

Comment: it means that in the localization YML file, the value `23.99`, or `neg` or whatever it is, is nested under another value `hourly_pay` - it's just a way of organizing my YML file. Say I a list of vegetables I want to localize. I could just call `t('cucumber')` and `t('lettuce')` but I'd much rather organize them under the category `vegetables` in my YML file, and so when I localize, I'd call `t('vegetables.cucumber')`, for example. However, this is unrelated to the question - I'm asking about refactoring the `each` block and if I have to declare `@hourly_pay` before the block, for example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention is not very clear here but I suggest that you look at using the index_by method in enumerable class. You'll get the complete HourlyPay object as the value in the hash though and can get the hash in one line.

Consider putting this code in the model if not already there.